# MVP - Destroy Presenter object from View Controller on dismiss in iOS

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, mvp

I'm following [Example Here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/devinsolsnippets/EeGxxa) to apply MVP pattern in swift. 
When I dismiss my View Controller, the presenter is not destroyed and View Controller also remains in memory.

When I try to make the presenter object 'weak', the code break at this line.

```
presenter.login(email: "email", password: "password")
```

How can I properly declare and destroy the presenter instance. Thanks

Comment: Can you post your `ViewController` code?

Comment: Add some code of your ViewController and Presenter.

Comment: The code can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/snippets/devinsolsnippets/EeGxxa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code in `Presenter` you create request to network and capture self in closure without using weak or unowned reference. Because of this there is a retain cycle. You can read more about retain cycles [here](http://www.thomashanning.com/retain-cycles-weak-unowned-swift/).

Updated code:

```
func login(email: String, password: String)
{
    self.view.showProgress()

    FoodAPI.api.login(email: email, password: password) { [weak self] (msg, user) in
        guard let `self` = self else {
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.view.hideProgress()
            if let user = user
            {
                AppDelegate.shared.user = user
                UserDefaultsHelper.saveUser(user: user)
                self.view.openMenu() //this line will dismiss the VC and presents next one. 
            }else
            {
                self.view.showAlert(message: msg)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to see advanced usage of **MVP** pattern you can checkout my open project [here](https://github.com/ismetanin/Notty) and feel free to ask me anything.

Comment: Yes. I have updated the code with network call now. Can you please suggest some fix. Thanks. 
https://bitbucket.org/snippets/devinsolsnippets/EeGxxa

Comment: If I explicitly make the presenter null in viewWillDisapear(), the issue gets resolved but I know that not a proper solution.

Comment: If I explicitly make the presenter null in viewWillDisapear(), the issue gets resolved but I know that not a proper solution.

Comment: Great, Man. It helped. <3